# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$v' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Tags: php

I created one class and created some member variables ,

i am not getting why this error is coming ,when ever i am writing private or public access specifiers before the memeber variables , then error is disappering ,

what is the reason behid it.

is it not taking public as default ??

code

```html
<?php
class abc
{
    $v = "g";

 $array = ['name'=>'test','age'=>5];

}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: You claim to know php. And cakephp framework. Did you lie in your profile description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP class member declarations require a visibility keyword (`public`, `protected`, or `private`) or the deprecated `var` keyword.  When using `var`, the visibility will be public.

You may have gotten mixed up with class method declarations, where the visibility keyword can be omitted, defaulting to public visibility.

Comment: so by default is private , is it ?

Comment: @sradha The default visibility is never private in PHP.  For class members (properties) there *must* be one of the above-mentioned keywords used to declare the member variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just correct by this

```
<?php
class abc
{
    protected $v = "g";

    protected $array = ['name'=>'test','age'=>5];

}
```

The reason ? it's just what @faintsignal says.